# How to do $ \bigotimes_{i=1}^n A_i $ where $ A_i $ is a $ m \times m $ matrix?

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, tensors

$$
\bigotimes_{i=1}^n A_i
$$

where $ A_i $ is a $ m \times m $ matrix.

I want to do above operation, however `KroneckerProduct` in *Mathematica* must list all $ A_i $s I need to use.

I have a function $ A_i $ where $ i\in \mathbb{Z} $, and I want to write a program which doesn't depend on specific $ n $. I know I can write a recursion, but I want to know whether there is more clever method.

Comment: Something like `KroneckerProduct @@ Table[A[i], {i, n}]`?

Comment: @CarlWoll Nice, thank you.

Comment: also `Array[A, {n}, 1, KroneckerProduct]`?

Comment: @kglr `{n}` can be just `n` here.

Comment: @ΑλέξανδροςΖεγγ, right; thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
kP[a_, n_Integer] := Array[a, n, 1, KroneckerProduct]
kP[a_, 1] := a[1]

kP[A, 5]
```

> KroneckerProduct[A[1], A[2], A[3], A[4], A[5]]

Comment: Note, that for $n=1$ a special case is required or `Unprotect@KroneckerProduct;
KroneckerProduct[m_] := m`.

Comment: @Johu, good point; added the special case.